# Is there a syntax for the path of a file in the current or a parent directory?

Tags: files

I am writing a template engine and I would like to allow users to refer to a file at the current directory, but if it doesn't exist, look at the parent directory, and so on up to the `source/` directory, which is the root of the templates source tree in my case.

This allows easy overriding of file inclusions and resolving different files based on location (useful for things like internationalization).

Is there any syntax that is commonly used for things like this?

Comment: Don't know of such a thing in Bash, nor in Perl and such. However you might want to pursue two paths. One goes like `pwd | tr '/' '\n'` and write backwards for loop until you reach sources. The other goes like `cd ..` in a series, check for file, and hopping up one directory after another *recursivly*, until sources is reached again.

Comment: Thanks... but what I want is actually a syntax to use for representing this, I am implementing the actual path lookup in Go... I was thinking of using something like `.../file.txt` which would resolve to `./file.txt` if it exists, `../file.txt/ or `../../file.txt` up until `source/file.txt`.

Comment: It's hard to give a negative answer to a question of "Does X exist", but in all the time I've used Linux (or any OS, really), I don't think I've ever heard of a usual syntax for that. If you're looking for suggestions on what syntax to use, well, then that just depends on what you like best... If looking up files from the whole tree is going to be the common case, then why not just have plain `file.txt` do that?

Comment: Maybe you should go forth and invent this.  Actually, the only way I know of is in the opposite direction, which I think most people will call globbing in command shells and such. E.g., in zsh you can find all text files down a directory tree with `ls -l **/*.txt`. Is it correct that you want something like that, but in an upwards direction?  Bet, doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks @Micha. Yes, you're correct. I've seen this in other templating systems but they didn't have a syntax for that, it was just the "convention" in some directory structures... I will then just be creative and invent it :D I like `.../file.txt`, it makes sense to me at least.

Comment: Yes, very much so.

Comment: @Renato Do you think you might eventually answer this question yourself? I came across this question in the Close Votes queue but I don't want to vote-to-close if it would prevent you from self-answering.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I answered it now.

Comment: Cool! Welcome to [unix.se]!

Answer (score 0):

After a few days waiting, looks like no one knows of a common syntax for this.

As I am writing the system that resolves the paths myself, I will just go with what I hope makes sense: `.../file` will refer to any file in the current directory or an ancestor directory, up to the `source/` directory which is my "root".

My templates look something like this:

```
<div>{{ include path }}</div>
```

This will include the file called `path` on the same directory as the file as this is on.

If the path were absolute, as `/path`, then it would resolve to `source/path`.

Now, with this new syntax, given a file at `source/abc/def/ghi/other-file` with these contents:

```
<div>{{ include .../path }}</div>
```

The included file could be located at any of:

```
source/path
source/abc/path
source/abc/def/path
source/abc/def/ghi/path
```

This allows me to have features like internationalization by structuring directories like this:

```
source/en/_messages
source/sv/_messages
```

Now, I can have a shared file that, depending on where it's included from, gets populated with messages from whatever locale the inclusion is on by simply declaring:

```
{{ include .../_messages }}
```

Comment: You've explained the syntax, alright. It looks like it works similar to how `.htaccess` files are interpreted by Apache. Unfortunately, without an implementation that's generally applicable to Unix filesystems, I'm not sure this is on-topic for this site. [so] or [programmers.se] might be a better fit.

Comment: I agree the answer turned out to be more related to the design of my own system, but the question was simply if syntax for this exists in the Unix world. I am still willing to accept someone's definitive answer to that... but was asked to just answer the question myself and decided to do it with my conclusions. Close if you prefer, no problem for me.